# With a scanner search on ArrayList the content and print the line

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I have a text file (.txt) and I'm stuck here.
I user a BufferReader to read all file and save in a ArrayList then put the ArrayList into a String to remove the , [ ]
Now I need to find the word of the scanner ex: (1001) in the ArrayList that the user want, and print the line of this word and the 4 lines after that. After that, edit this 4 lines and save the ArrayList to a file.

Or have something more simple without using ArrayLists?
Thank you.

```
System.out.println("Digite o ID ou 1 para sair: ");
                Scanner sOPFicheiro = new Scanner(System.in);
                opFicheiro = sOPFicheiro.nextInt();
                     if (opFicheiro == 1){
                         System.out.println("A voltar ao menu anterior...");
                         Thread.sleep(1000);
                         editarFicheiro();
                     } else {
                            //Envia para um ArrayList o ficheiro Formandos
                            ArrayList<String> textoFormandos = new ArrayList<String>();
                            BufferedReader ler = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FichFormandos));
                            String linha;
                        while ((linha = ler.readLine()) != null) {
                            textoFormandos.add(linha + "\n");
                        }
                        ler.close();
                              
                              //Remove , [ ] do ArrayList para enviar para o ficheiro
                              String textoFormandos2 = Arrays.toString(textoFormandos.toArray()).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "");
                         
                     }
```

File:
[Txt File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A5sp.png)

Comment: With the full text, you could do with a regular expression like: `/termIAmLookingfor\..*\..*\..*\..*/g`. I am not sure I fully understand what you want and as such my regex may not be exactly what you want. But it should show you how you could do it

Comment: what has to be done in case if `there's no line` in the file with an integer entered by the user?

Comment: "4 lines and save the ArrayList to a file" this statement is unclear. I assume that after the method execution a file containing lines that have been found must be created, is that correct?

Comment: @César Guimarães you need first to write the full source code in English even the comments you put inside it at least I don't speak Portuguese. Also try to fix the description of what you are trying to get from the text file. You have published the text file. Tell us what you expect to extract from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> save the ArrayList to a file

Your code lucks a mean to write data into the file.

Also invoking `close()` without a `try/catch` is a bad practice because it'll lead to resource leaks in case of exceptions.

For this task, you don't need a list, after the match with the given `id` is found you can write these lines to a file.

To execute this code file **`"test.txt"`** must reside under the project folder, file **`"result.txt"`** will be created automatically.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                readFile(Path.of("test.txt"), Path.of("result.txt"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    public static void readFile(Path target, Path result) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner sOPFicheiro = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opFicheiro = sOPFicheiro.nextInt();
        if (opFicheiro == 1) {
            System.out.println("A voltar ao menu anterior...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            editarFicheiro();
        } else {

            try (BufferedReader ler = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(target.toFile()));
                 BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(result.toFile()))) {
                boolean matchIsFound = false;
                String linha;
                while ((linha = ler.readLine()) != null && !matchIsFound) {
                    if (linha.contains(String.valueOf(opFicheiro))) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            br.write(linha);
                            if (i != 4) {
                                br.newLine();
                                linha = ler.readLine();
                            }
                        }
                        matchIsFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**user input** - `1001`

Initial contents of the **`"test.txt"`** file:

```
ID: 999
Name: ________________
Data of birth: _______
NIF: _________________
Telephone: ___________
Fim ID: 999

ID: 1001
Name: Cesar Rodrige da Silva Guimaraes
Data of birth: 16/03/2003
NIF: 1111111111
Telephone: 931111111111
Fim ID: 1001
```

Contents of the **`"result.txt"`** file after executing the code:

```
ID: 1001
Name: Cesar Rodrige da Silva Guimaraes
Data of birth: 16/03/2003
NIF: 1111111111
Telephone: 931111111111
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            updateUserData(Path.of("test.txt"), Path.of("temp.txt"));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
    public static void updateUserData(Path original, Path temp) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int id = scanner.nextInt();
        if (id == 1) {
            System.out.println("A voltar ao menu anterior...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            editarFicheiro();
            return;
        }

        String userData = readUserData(temp, id);
        String originalContentWithReplacement = readAndReplace(original, userData, id);
        writeData(original, originalContentWithReplacement);
    }
```

- reading user-data for the given `id` from the `temp` file

```
    public static String readUserData(Path temp, int id) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try (var reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(temp.toFile()))) {
            boolean matchIsFound = false;
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !matchIsFound) {
                if (line.contains(String.valueOf(id))) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++, line = reader.readLine()) {
                        result.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    }
                    matchIsFound = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString().stripTrailing();
    }
```

- reading the `whole contents` of the original file and replacing the data for the given `id`

```
    public static String readAndReplace(Path original, String userData, int id) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try (var reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(original.toFile()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.contains(String.valueOf(id))) {
                    result.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    continue;
                }

                result.append(userData).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString().stripTrailing();
    }
```

- replacing the previous data

```
    public static void writeData(Path original, String content) {
        try (var writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(original.toFile()))) {
            writer.write(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And it's working, it's puting in a temp file, thanks.

Comment: I have 1 question, how I can put the temp file to the original file in the specific line of ID?

Comment: @CésarGuimarães you want to `replace all the contents` of the original file `with only 5 lines with info for the given id`?

Comment: @CésarGuimarães that's doable, but almost all the original data will be lost. Please confirm that my understanding is correct or if I got it wrong, correct me.

Comment: I want to replace with the 4 lines in tempfile to the original file without delete the other lines in original file ID:1002, 1003... .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `ArrayList` use a `StringBuilder` :

```
    StringBuilder textoFormandos = new StringBuilder();
    while ...
        textoFormandos.append(linha + "\n");
    ...
    String textoFormandos2 = textoFormandos.toString();
```

This way you won't need to remove anything. For the rest you need to clear the requirements.